# How to check for existence of null in a table column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I have a table ( application)  with the following columns:

```
appID
ssn
fname
lname
```

What I want to do is scan the appID column is null exist. If there is one, then execute a stored procedure called NullFix.Any suggestion as to how to construct the SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how many records are `null` with `count()`

```
if (select count(*) from application where appID is null) > 0 
begin
    exec procName
end
else
begin
    -- do other stuff
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if count is needed at all. You could better use EXISTS, which might (and should) perform faster.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM application WHERE appID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    EXEC procName;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --other stuff :)
END
```